# Problema con código java

Tags: java

Código:

```
public class Tarea1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String uno= in.nextLine();
        String dos= in.nextLine();
        char [] letras= new char[dos.length()];
        boolean [] esta= new boolean [dos.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < dos.length(); i++) {
            letras[i]=dos.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < esta.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < uno.length(); j++) {
                if (uno.charAt(j)==letras[i]){
                    esta[i]=true;
                }
            }
        }
        int aux=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < esta.length; i++) {
            if (esta[i]==true) {
                aux++;
            }
        }
        if (aux==dos.length()) {
            System.out.println("SI");
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probé tu código y en los dos casos devuelve SI, puedes poner más detalle sobre cómo obtienes el error?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void campareStrings(String string1 , String string2){
    Char[] aChar1 = string1.toChartArray();
    Char[] aChar2 = string2.toChartArray();
    Boolean existChart = true;

    for( Char x: aChar2 ){
        for( int i = 0; i < aChar1.length; i++){
            if(x  == aChar1[i]){
                break;
            }
            if((i == aChar1.length-1) && (x  =! aChar1[i])){
                existChart = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(existChart){
        System.out.println("Si"); 
    }else{
        System.out.println("No");
    }

}
```

Hace años que no programo en Java, así que no sé si tiene errores de sintaxis :p

Comment: ¿Por qué en inglés? ¿Dónde obtuviste el código?

Comment: Es mi código, siempre programo en ingles con el fin de internacionalizarlo

Comment: Me refería en donde dice **try this:**, la respuesta tendría que estar en español.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que al fin encontré una posible solución

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compara {

    private Scanner sc;
    private String txt1, txt2;
    private ArrayList<Character> lista1, lista2;

    public Compara() {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        txt1 = sc.nextLine();
        txt2 = sc.nextLine();
        lista1 = crearLista(txt1);
        lista2 = crearLista(txt2);
        comparar(lista1, lista2);
    }

    //Función que devuelve un ArrayList tipo char
    public ArrayList<Character> crearLista(String txt) {
        char[] letras = txt.toCharArray();
        ArrayList<Character> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < letras.length; i++) {
            lista.add(letras[i]);
        }
        return lista;
    }

    /*Función recursiva, compara el primer carácter de lista2, y lo compara con 
    cada una de los caracteres de lista1, si es igual, se eliminan ambas, y se 
    invoca de nuevo la función para que se actualice tanto la posición 0 de la 
    lista 2, como el tamaño de la lista1 para el for. Si no es igual, se suma 1 
    al contador, y si el contador es igual al tamaño de lista1, quiere decir que
    no tuvo coincidencias, por lo tanto es diferente.
    */
    public void comparar(ArrayList<Character> lista1, ArrayList<Character> lista2) {
        int contador = 0;
        if (lista1.size() > lista2.size()) {
            if (lista2.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lista1.size(); i++) {
                    if (lista2.get(0).equals(lista1.get(i))) {
                        lista1.remove(i);
                        lista2.remove(0);
                        comparar(lista1, lista2);
                        break;//Finaliza el for
                    } else {
                        contador++;
                    }
                    if (contador == lista1.size()) {
                        System.out.println("NO");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("SI");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("El segundo texto tiene mas letras.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Compara();
    }
}
```

Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar.
Saludos.